# Using REGEX to match a previous match

Tags: regex

Is this even possible to do using `Regex`:

For example, I have 2 strings
"**helhelhel**" and "**helhalhal**"

With the regex `([a-z]{3})+` I can match both.

But I'm thinking of an expression where

- the first string will match - because the first match "**hel**" repeats 3 times*
- while the second doesn't match - because the first match is "**hel**" and second & third is different, "**hal**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back references to match the text previously matched by the regex. Inorder to do this you need to use the buffers provided by the regex. 
`([a-z]{3})\1` will match three letter words repeated twice.
This will match `haihai`, but not `haihui`.

The notation `()` stores its content to a buffer provided by regex. `\1` is referring to the content of this buffer.